# Is there any deep-link to open Skype/Contacts on Android?

Tags: android, html, deep-linking, skype

There is the view(html page) with link button referred to Skype/Contacts. When user clicks on this button from browser on Android this link goes to recent chats in Skype App. But I Want link referred to Contacts tab in Skype App. For example this link : 'viber://contacts' in Viber goes to contacts tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `skype://chat`
It worked for me.

Comment: skype://username